# Webpage testing using Robotium 4.3

Tags: android, android-webview, robotium

I have a sample app which opens google search page in a webview. I want to hit the search button. But get an error that the element could not be found. Is it possible to automate a webpage loaded in webview? If so what is missing in my code? Please suggest..

App Code(relevant):

```
 setContentView(R.layout.webview);
 webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1);
 webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
 webView.loadUrl("http://www.google.com");
```

Testing Code:

```
Button myView = solo.getView(Button.class, 0);
solo.waitForView(myView, 20, false);
solo.clickOnView(myView);
WebView view = solo.getView(WebView.class, 0);
solo.waitForView(view, 100000, false);
solo.clickOnWebElement(By.id("gbqfb"));
```

Error is at solo.clickOnWebElement

Error:

```
junit.framework.AssertionFailedError: WebElement with id: 'gbqfb' is not found!
at com.jayway.android.robotium.solo.Clicker.clickOnWebElement(Clicker.java:343)
at com.jayway.android.robotium.solo.Solo.clickOnWebElement(Solo.java:890)
at com.calculator.test.TestApk.testSpinnerlist(TestApk.java:51)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at android.test.InstrumentationTestCase.runMethod(InstrumentationTestCase.java:214)
at android.test.InstrumentationTestCase.runTest(InstrumentationTestCase.java:199)
at     android.test.ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2.runTest(ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2.java:192)
at android.test.AndroidTestRunner.runTest(AndroidTestRunner.java:191)
at android.test.AndroidTestRunner.runTest(AndroidTestRunner.java:176)
at android.test.InstrumentationTestRunner.onStart(InstrumentationTestRunner.java:554)
at android.app.Instrumentation$InstrumentationThread.run(Instrumentation.java:1701)
```

The screenshot taken by UI Automator Viewer shows the entire page as (package -com.android.browser, class - android.webkit.WebView) but does not identify the other objects on the page.

Environment - Android4.3, Robotium4.3, Emulator, Windows7 x32

PS-On Emulator, the search button(id=gbqfb) comes by default. Also tried to type something in the search textfield but that also failed with similar reason. solo.typeTextInWebElement(By.id("gbqfq"), "testing")

Answer (score 1):

Google changes the id of the input field. Try looking for `By.name("q")` instead

Answer (score 0):

I don't see id "gbqfb" on google page. Did you mean class "gbqfbb"? - Then it should look like:

```
solo.clickOnWebElement(By.className("gbqfbb"));
```

Comment: You don't have enter text in your code, so this button cannot be found

Comment: On the emulator it comes by default

Comment: Even type in the search field failed with similar reason. solo.typeTextInWebElement(By.id("gbqfq"), "testing")